# NSTimer and NSDateFormatter trouble. My timerLabel is disappearing upon refresh?

Tags: ios, nstimer, nsdateformatter

I have a UIDatePicker on one viewController that allows the user to set a calendar date, hour, and minute in the form of (sun July 22nd, 2:33pm) for a timer to be used in a separate viewController. On the separate viewController I am trying to have the timer displayed in an overlay on the UIImagePickerController in the form of 'dd:hh:mm:ss' left between the current NSDate (todays date/time) and the chosen datePicker date. Basically it's a countdown timer that starts counting down days, hours, minutes, seconds from the selected picker date, when the camera loads. My problem is that once the camera loads, the timer displays the correct remaining time in the correct format but then quickly disappears when it get's to my refreshLabel method. I Logged the values for my timerLabel and it is displaying correctly in the log but once the loop runs once it returns Null for everything. I had some help last night in determining that my problem could most likely be with the formatting of the date from string but I don't see what it is that could be wrong since the correct date is initially displayed when the camera first loads. So here's my code from my first viewController with the datePicker that sets the timerLabels time:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDate"]) {
        NSString *textFieldContents = self.textField.text;
        NSString *counterContents = self.counter;
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
        NSString *deadline = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/deadline.txt",
                              documentsDirectory];
        NSString *flashName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/flashName.txt",
                               documentsDirectory];
        NSError *fileError;
        [textFieldContents writeToFile:flashName
                            atomically:YES
                              encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                                 error:&fileError];
        [counterContents writeToFile:deadline
                           atomically:YES
                             encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                                error:&fileError];
        if(fileError.code == 0){
            NSLog(@"deadline.txt was written successfully with these contents: %@,", 
                  counterContents);
            NSLog(@"flashName.txt was written successfully with these contents: %@,",
                  textFieldContents);}
        else
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDate" sender:self];}
}

-(IBAction)refreshLabel; {

        NSDate *selected = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[picker.date timeIntervalSince1970] - 1];
        self.counter = [self.formatter stringFromDate:selected];
        NSLog(@"selected is: %@", selected);
        NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];

        NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

        NSUInteger unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
        NSDateComponents *dateComparisonComponents = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:todaysDate toDate:selected options:NSWrapCalendarComponents];
        NSInteger days = [dateComparisonComponents day];
        NSInteger hours = [dateComparisonComponents hour];
        NSInteger minutes = [dateComparisonComponents minute];
        NSInteger seconds = [dateComparisonComponents second];

        self.counter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld:%02ld:%02ld:%02ld", (long)days, (long)hours, (long)minutes, (long)seconds];
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
        NSString *deadline = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/deadline.txt", documentsDirectory];
        NSInteger success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:selected toFile:deadline];
        NSLog(@"success is: %d",success);
    }e *selected = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[picker date] timeIntervalSince1970] - 1];

- (void)viewDidLoad
{   [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textField.delegate = self;

    self.formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [self.formatter setDateFormat:@"dd:hh:mm:ss"];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    picker.minimumDate = [NSDate date];
    picker.maximumDate = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:604800];

    [picker setDate:now animated:YES];
    self.counter = [now description];

    self.now = [NSDate date];
    self.counter = [self.formatter stringFromDate:self.now];}
```

And here's my viewController code for the UIImagePickerController that I need to have the timerLabel displayed and counting down correctly:

```
  - (IBAction)startCamera:(id)sender {
    if (self.image == nil &&  [self.videoFilePath length] == 0) {
        self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
        self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
        self.imagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 10;

        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
            self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        }
        else {
            self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        }
        self.imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:self.imagePickerController.sourceType];
        [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:NO completion:nil];}

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OverlayView" owner:self options:nil];
    self.overlayView.frame = CGRectMake(160,8,0,0);
    self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayView;

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *deadline = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/deadline.txt",
                          documentsDirectory];
    NSString *flashName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/flashName.txt",
                           documentsDirectory];
    NSError *fileError;
    titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:flashName
                                                encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                   error:&fileError];
    timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:deadline
                                                encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                   error:&fileError];
    if(fileError.code == 0){
        NSLog(@"deadline.txt was read successfully with these contents: %@,",
              timerLabel.text);
        NSLog(@"flashName.txt was read successfully with these contents: %@,",
              titleLabel.text);}

    self.startDate = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:deadline];
    [self refreshLabel];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(refreshLabel)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
}

-(void)refreshLabel {

    NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *dateComparisonComponents = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:todaysDate toDate:self.startDate options:NSWrapCalendarComponents];
    NSInteger days = [dateComparisonComponents day];
    NSInteger hours = [dateComparisonComponents hour];
    NSInteger minutes = [dateComparisonComponents minute];
    NSInteger seconds = [dateComparisonComponents second];

    self.timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld:%02ld:%02ld:%02ld", (long)days, (long)hours, (long)minutes, (long)seconds];
    if (days == 0 && hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
        [self.timer invalidate];
        NSLog(@"Time's up!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion last night, you can't use a date formatter this way, because you're looking at time in the future like 1 day 2 hours 5 minutes, not a date. One way to do this, would be to pass the picker's selected date to the image picker controller, and do pretty much the same thing you did in the first controller to get the date components. So in the first controller, save the picker date to the file rather than a string:

```
-(IBAction)refreshLabel; {

    NSDate *selected = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[picker.date timeIntervalSince1970] - 1];
    self.counter = [self.formatter stringFromDate:selected];
    NSLog(@"selected is: %@", selected);
    NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    dateComparisonComponents = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:todaysDate toDate:selected options:NSWrapCalendarComponents];
    NSInteger days = [dateComparisonComponents day];
    NSInteger hours = [dateComparisonComponents hour];
    NSInteger minutes = [dateComparisonComponents minute];
    NSInteger seconds = [dateComparisonComponents second];

    self.counter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld:%02ld:%02ld:%02ld", (long)days, (long)hours, (long)minutes, (long)seconds];
    self.textField.text = self.counter;
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *deadline = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/deadline.txt", documentsDirectory];
    NSInteger success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:selected toFile:deadline];
    NSLog(@"success is: %d",success);
}
```

Then in the image picker controller (I'm only showing the code needed for the timer label):

```
- (IBAction)startCamera:(id)sender {

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *deadline = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/deadline.txt", documentsDirectory];
    NSError *fileError;
    self.startDate = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:deadline];
    [self refreshLabel];
    if(fileError.code == 0){
        NSLog(@"deadline.txt was read successfully with these contents: %@,", self.timerLabel.text);
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(refreshLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}


-(void)refreshLabel{
    NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *dateComparisonComponents = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:todaysDate toDate:self.startDate options:NSWrapCalendarComponents];
    NSInteger days = [dateComparisonComponents day];
    NSInteger hours = [dateComparisonComponents hour];
    NSInteger minutes = [dateComparisonComponents minute];
    NSInteger seconds = [dateComparisonComponents second];

    self.timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld:%02ld:%02ld:%02ld", (long)days, (long)hours, (long)minutes, (long)seconds];
    if (days == 0 && hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
        [self.timer invalidate];
        NSLog(@"Time's up!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I get what your saying about improperly formatting for a calendar date rather than a number of days, I was thinking about it all wrong. Now, however, when I run the app after making the changes I get this error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive (0x31, 0x3a, 0x32, 0x33, 0x3a, 0x35, 0x39, 0x3a)' The line that throws it is: self.startDate = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:deadline]; Is that a formatting error also?

Comment: @JaredGross, It works fine when I tested it. Do you have the same lines as what I posted in the refreshLabel method in the first controller? Is success logging 1?

Comment: I removed the line for `self.textField.text = self.counter;` because it was changing the textfield on my first controller to display the time when it needs to read the user input for titleLabel and save that instead. Everything is logging correctly though still, so I'm once again at a loss.

Comment: @JaredGross, why are you saving the data to a file in the first place? Do you need this data to be persistent across launches of the app?

Comment: yes. I need both the timerLabel and titleLabel's data to be persistent between launches. Basically when the app runs, after the user has set the timer initially, I want the imagePickerController to be the only screen that loads until the timer is up or the user cancels the imagePicker (sorry, I should have made that more clear to begin with)

Comment: @JaredGross, Well, I don't know why yours isn't working now, since the code I posted worked fine for me. You should update your question to show what code you are now using.

Comment: okay. I have updated my code to it's current state. I didn't modify your original code except to fit it into my already existing code. I have a feeling it's something simple again that I am missing.

Comment: @JaredGross, You're writing to the file deadline twice in your first controller. Once in refreshLabel where you write out the date as an NSData object, and again in prepareForSegue, where you're writing out a string -- that will overwrite your first one. If you want to pass that string too, you should make a new file name for it.